# Run a function whenever Karma tests fail

Tags: api, jasmine, karma-runner

I have been asked to have Karma run on our live server so that whenever a unit test fails an email is dispatched, and I haven't been able to find any answers related to this.

Do any of you know of a way to run a function when Karma tests fail? I am running with Jasmine, specifically. Are there any other parts to the public API outside of just the ways to start the Karma server (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/dev/public-api.html)? Maybe something like a `require('karma').server.onTestFail`?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Typically this would be done by the Continuous Integration server, for instance [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). If you don't use it, I would recommend so.

If you really want to implement this in Karma, you can write a custom reporter, there is a method [onSpecComplete](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/415d0257c23ff7be07e240648bfff0bdefa9b0b6/lib/reporters/base.js#L79).